# Use global variable in extended class

Tags: java, groovy, junit, extend

Currently I have a strange behavior of my test.
For my test I'm using Groovy and JUnit 4. Groovy has his own strang logic, so don't worry about my code :D

Example 1:

```
@Log
class Test {
    private static def filledFormFields = [
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    ]

    @Before
    void check() {
        filledFormFields.each { k, v ->
            log.info("$k -> $v")
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testA() {
        System.exit(0)
    }
}
```

log.info prints all information of filledFormFields (even it is static, yes it has to be static in my case).

Example 2:

```
@Log
class Test extends Manager {
    private static def filledFormFields = [
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    ]

    @Test
    void testA() {
        System.exit(0)
    }
}

@Log
abstract class Manager {
    @Before
    void check() {
        filledFormFields.each { k, v ->
            log.info("$k -> $v")
        }
    }
}
```

log.info prints nothing, but why?

Why is my filledFormFields static?
Currently I'm creating Selenium/Geb JUnit Tests with Groovy. Each test instantiates the filledFormFields  variable new. In my case I don't want that, because of that it's static. Also it's private because I have multiple test classes that useses this variable just with other equally other information. That was the only solution that I found to keep the varibales only in a class and not instantiated on every test.

Comment: try removing the Log annotation from the Test class... it already inherits that annotation from Manager.

Comment: It's fine to have a static field in your test, but make sure to make it final and call `asImmutable()` to avoid share mutable state  between tests, which could cause you headaches.

Comment: Another comment, sorry: when you log something and then immediately call System.exit(), you should expect that the JVM may not have been done with writing the log to a file before dying. If you need the log to be done before you kill the JVM, check the logging framework documentation on how to achieve non-async logging.